# Turning CSV into rows not columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, csv

I have a file with unique references in column A (e.g.company names) and one or more values returned related to that unique value in column B (e.g.accounts). These are comma separated, some companies have one account only, some have many. Using 'text to columns' I then get all account numbers in separate columns on the same row as the company name.

What I'd like to do instead is get each account number on a new row, each with the corresponding company name so I then have a sheet just 2 columns wide and searchable on individual account level whilst referring back to the correct company. Is that possible?

Comment: Hi! You say column A in the CSV is unique references, yet you seem to also say that a company may have multiple accounts, each with a company name, which in my mind conflicts. :)  Can you post some of the lines from the CSV showing both what a company with as single account looks like as well as a company with multiple accounts?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, say I have 3 companies called A, B and C, company A has account number A123 only, company B has 2 accounts, A543 and A765 and company C has 3 accounts, A933, A403 and A221. They are all unique values (duplicates of account numbers and companies is impossible in this system). Can I get it so there are 6 lines each with the 6 individual accounts and the corresponding company?

Comment: This isn't an Excel answer so I'll just add it as a comment, but when I'm faced with stuff like this, I just write a little perl script to transform the csv into the form I want, so something that takes "A,A123;B,A543,A765;C,A933,A403,A221" (; meaning end-of-line) and spits out "A,A123;B,A543;B,A765;C,A933;C,A403;C,A221", which you can then just import into Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use excel formulas to "manually" delimit your data. If you use this formula, it will find the first occurrence of a comma and then trim to that occurrence:

```
=IF(A1="","",IFERROR(MID(A1,1,FIND(",",A1)-1),A1))
```

Under the cell that we have our initial data (in our case A1 is our initial data), we need to index the data to not include what we just removed:

```
=MID(A1,LEN(B1)+2,LEN(A1))
```

Here is it all working together:

[image]

Comment: I'm either not understanding the question or your answer (or both :-) ). Where is the company name, and how would it work with multiple companies (like the example @JonnieB added after you posted this answer)?

Comment: @blm His original post was about using the "text to columns" feature to split his data into rows instead.. He later changed his question after I posted this so I am not really sure anymore what he is after..

Comment: Hi guys, sorry if I've not been clear. When I mentioned 'text to columns' it was just referencing a function that does something similar to what I want but not exactly. I want to be able to take the following data

Comment: Column A, my companies: (in cell A1) Verizon, (A2) Vodafone, (A3) Telefonica

Comment: Column B, the accounts they have: (in cell B1 - indicating the account numbers of Verizon) 123456,234567, (B2)345678, (B3) 987654,876543,765432

Comment: and turn it into:
Column A, (A1) Verizon, (A2) Verizon, (A3) Vodafone, (A4) Telefonica, (A5) Telefonica, (A6) Telefonica
and
Column B, (B1) 123456, (B2) 234567, (B3) 345678, (B4) 987654, (B5) 876543, (B6) 765432

Comment: This then means I have one line per account number and the corresponding company alongside it. Is this possible?

Comment: And I should clarify, the file is an excel file, not a .csv file, it is just that Column B has comma separated values in it. Think that may have confused the matter...

Answer (score 0):

@Jonnie,
If you would use TextToColumns to spread the accountnumbers over various columns.
Then go to menu 'Screen' and click the icon above Macro's on the right. Enter a name for the macro and click 'create'. Then paste the code below between the two lines with sub.
Close the VBA window to return to your data. Click anywhere in the data. Click the Macro's icon again, choose your macroname and click Run.

```
Dim data As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Set data = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion 'Selecting the active region

For i = data.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1 'for all row (start at bottom)
    For j = 3 To data.Columns.Count 'for all columns (start at third column)
        If Not IsEmpty(data(i, j)) Then 'if there is a value
            data.Rows(i + 1).Insert 'insert a new row below
            data(i + 1, 1) = data(i, 1) 'copy the company
            data(i + 1, 2) = data(i, j) 'copy the account number
            data(i, j).Clear 'delete the original value
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

That should result in a list of

```
company A; accno 1
company A; accno 2
company B; accno 3
company C; accno 4
```

Comment: Joost, thanks for that but I've not written VBA/macros before so I don't know which bits to substitute the values of my columns/rows etc or how to the 'run' the macro. The result you are providing is what I am after though. Could you break it down into excel-moron speak for me, please (like, hit alt+F11 to open the VBA, then select the sheet you are working in from VBA Project etc)?

Comment: @JonnieB I edited my answer to explain the process. Sorry if I didn't get the wording completely right, I am on a Dutch Excel 2016 version.